# Iterating through HashMap by values

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I need to loop through a HashMap, but to give importance to the values' order.
For example, consider the following hash map of `<String, Integer>`:

```
{"dog" : 2, "bird": 3, "cat" : 1}
```

Now, I need to loop through the hasp map in order of ascending values, so that

```
for () {
 System.out.println( currentKey );
}
```

will always output

> "cat", "dog", "bird"

Comment: In your question, your keys and values both sort the same way, and so it's easy to misunderstand your question. If the map were `{"r" : 2, "q": 3, "z" : 1}`, would you want `z r q` (the order according to the values 1, 2, 3) or `q r z`? You've said "values' order" and so I *assume* you want `z r q` (the order according to the values 1, 2, 3), but... Also, can there be duplicate values? E.g., `{"r" : 2, "q": 3, "z" : 1, "w": 1}` (there are two entries with the value `1`). If so, what order do you want them in? By key? Indeterminate?

Comment: You fixed the first part, not the second: *"Also, can there be duplicate values? E.g., `{"r" : 2, "q": 3, "z" : 1, "w": 1}` (there are two entries with the value `1`). If so, what order do you want them in? By key? Indeterminate?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the map sort itself by value as you insert entries then the easiest way would probably be to use something like the [TreeMultimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) in Google's collections library.

If you still want to use a hashmap but have the values sorted when you retrieve them from the set, then you can take two approaches - either you can get the values using the values() method and then run Collections.sort() on the returned list, or you can again use a class like TreeMultimap, adding all the entries in the current hashmap and then enumerating through them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you may be interested in instead using a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which sorts your entries by key.

Otherwise, you may be interested looking into [Map.keySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()), [Map.entrySet(),](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) or [Map.values()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()).

If you still want to keep your Map a HashMap, you could use one of [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)' numerous functions for getting sorted collections (e.g. you could get a sorted version of your map, sort a list, etc).

Since I see you specifically want to sort by values, I think [Michał Minicki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767249/iterating-through-hashmap-by-values/4767280#4767280)'s answer ought to be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help:

[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Another example using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

Pros:

- Returns entries (not just keys)
- Does not require the keys to be `Comparable`

```
static <K, V>Set<Map.Entry<V, K>>
entriesByValue(Map<K, V> source, Comparator<V> cmp) {
    SortedMap<V, Collection<K>> inverseMap = Maps.newTreeMap(cmp);
    Supplier<Set<K>> setFactory = new Supplier<Set<K>>() {
        public Set<K> get() {
            return Sets.newHashSet();
        }
    };
    SetMultimap<V, K> inverseMM =
        Multimaps.newSetMultimap(inverseMap, setFactory);
    Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(source), inverseMM);
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(inverseMM.entries());
}
```